# "Programmers" account missing in Accounts tab

Tags: support, linked-accounts

I am registered on programmers.stackexchange.com and posted a question there. I use the same OpenID as everywhere else to login and I think the account is linked to my other StackExchange accounts. However Programmers doesn't appear in my Accounts tab.

Is this a bug? Or do I need to do something to make it show up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [your profile](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/33606/laurent) on Programmers and it looks linked to your network SE profile correctly. No idea why Programmers isn't showing up in your accounts list, though.

Try clearing all account associations using the button at the bottom of [this page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/166973/laurent?tab=accounts). It should automatically reassociate your accounts and Programmers should show up.

Comment: Yes that did the trick, thanks!